# Zend Framework switchting to native namespace

Tags: php, zend-framework, namespaces

since PHP 5.3 Zend Framework definetly supports namespace as I assume.
But the tutorials, examples, and also the ZF.sh tools still uses the old "fake" namespacing.

My question is, how do I get Zend using the new, real namespace system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing to do, their autoloader can find `My_Namespace_Class1` as well as `My\Namespace\Class1` (by replacing the namespace separator by "/" to find the file).

So you just have to use their autoloader and configure it the same way you would with old/fake namespaces.

Answer (score 2):

The ZF team is actively working on [ZF2](http://framework.zend.com/wiki/display/ZFDEV2/Zend+Framework+2.0+Roadmap), the next major version of ZF that would support native namespaces and is much faster. I remember Mathew Weierophinney (ZF core developer), said in a conference that in his initial tests the autoloading was 7 times faster than current version of ZF.